# if (<object> == <int>)

Tags: c#, object, if-statement, int

I can't understand, why the `if` statement in the picture below returns false.
I hope you can explain it to me.

You can see, that the values and the typs of both variables are the same.

[image]

Comment: Please, provide us more details. What is `value` in this case ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `==` operator you are calling is the overload that takes two `object` parameters. This uses reference equality - the value isn't important, it has to be *the same* object.

As you can read in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx):

> For reference types other than string, == **returns true if its two operands refer to the same object**. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.

While `int` is a value type, it has been ['boxed'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) (wrapped in an `object`). You are comparing the two different reference types that wrap your integers.

To fix this, you can use `object.Equals` instead - this will compare the two integers.

```
item.Equals(value);
```

Or the static method (which would handle the case where `item == null`):

```
object.Equals(item, value);
```

If you unbox to `int` then you can use the `int` overload of `==` as you expect:

```
(int)item == (int)value;
```

Again, per the docs:

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) **returns true if the values of its operands are equal.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the two object wrappers of `int` that you are comparing are different objects.

Since `object` does not override `==` with a call of `Equals`, the comparison checks references instead, and returns `false`, because the two objects are different.

You can use `object.Equals(item, value)` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast an `int` to an `object`, you are creating a new object. This is referred to as *boxing*.

Any comparison will then be an object comparison. With objects, the `==` operator will check if the references are the same. It will not check if the two variable reference equivalent objects, it will check if the two variables reference one object.

If you want to perform an int comparison, you must convert it back to an integer (unbox it).

Alternatively, you can use `Equals` instead of the `==` operator.

Here's a piece of code which demonstrates this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 3;
        object o1 = n;
        object o2 = n;
        Console.WriteLine("o1 == o2 is {0}", o1 == o2);
        Console.WriteLine("o1.Equals(o2) is {0}", o1.Equals(o2));
        Console.WriteLine("(int)o1 == (int)o2 is {0}", (int)o1 == (int)o2);

    }
}
```

The output:

> o1 == o2 is False
>
> o1.Equals(o2) is True
>
> (int)o1 == (int)o2 is True