# How to return multiple variables in propertys

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to return multiple variables in a property

```
public class Cars
{
    public object value { get; set; }
    public bool worked { get; set; }
}

public Cars GetCar(object value, Cars c)
{
   c.value = value;
   return c;
}

public void Main(string[] args)
{
   Cars c = new Cars();
   string mycar = "ABC-12";
   int mycar2 = 123;

   if (GetCar(mycar, c).value == "ABC") // working
       GetCar(mycar, c).worked = false;

   if (GetCar(mycar, c).value == 1) // error
       GetCar(mycar, c).worked = false;
}
```

So that if the object is a string that works but if I use that int I get that exception

> The == operator can not be applied to "object" and "int" operands

**Note**: I don't want use Convert.to every time

Comment: You've declared `value` as `object`, not `int`. Declare it as `int`.

Comment: value can be a int, string or ulong If I make it to int I cant use string anymore

Comment: So if it's a string, and it has the value "Fred", how do you expect to be able to compare it to the integer value `1`?

Comment: I think you dont understand It If I use example `GetCar(string, c)` then the value is a string

Comment: This looks like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you declaring `value` as an object, rather than using strong types?

Comment: If I use `public string value { get; set; }` then I need to convert it every time to a string

Comment: But surely this should be two properties, one string and one int. What do the values you're storing actually represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_System_Object_) method, this will cast both operands to `object` first:

```
        if (object.Equals(GetCar(mycar, c).value,"ABC")) // working
            GetCar(mycar, c).worked = false;

        if (object.Equals(GetCar(mycar2, c).value,1)) // compiles, and does not throw exception
            GetCar(mycar2, c).worked = false;
```

Comment: The OP has absolutely no clue, that's why he didn't accept your answer, the only correct answer so far. Funny

Comment: @BionicCode he posted that 1 hour ago but yea thats the better way. thanxs

Answer (score 1):

`mycar` is of type `object`. When you set  `string mycar = "ABC-12"`, you explicitly set it to be of type `string`.
So once you compare it with an int value you get an exception.

This should also help: [if (<object> == <int>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816503/if-object-int)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just missing a cast. On the other hand I must question your code - what are you trying to achieve? The things you are doing make a very little sense to me.

```
    public class Cars
    {
        public object value { get; set; }
        public bool worked { get; set; }
    }

    public Cars GetCar(object value)
    {
        Cars c = new Cars();
        c.value = value;
        return c;
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mycar = "ABC-12";
        int mycar2 = 123;

        if ((string)GetCar(mycar).value == "ABC")
            GetCar(mycar).worked = false;

        if ((int)GetCar(mycar2).value == 1) // changed mycar to mycar2 and 
                                            // added a cast to int
            GetCar(mycar2).worked = false;
    }
```

Comment: That will throw an exception if `value` is a string.

Comment: value is int in this case.

Comment: What about the case where it isn't an int? If it's always an int, why would it be declared as `object`?

Comment: My best guess is that this is due to the lack of understanding of subject from OP. Since the question is poorly written and formated, I've tried to be helpful to the OP in the first way. I totally get your point, which of course is correct but is it also of any use to OP?

Comment: that worked for me but Is it possibile to do that without (string) or (int) behind `GetCar()` ?

Comment: @schokoBong is there any specific reason to use data type object for property value?

Comment: I think he wants something like a variant so it can hold multiple value types. Maybe.

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes that is want I want ^^

Comment: anyway @MatějŠtágl thanxs for that I will use it in that way

Comment: Your code is unsafe. Using a direct cast from an `object` type is prone to throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

you ca try to edit the test like that:

```
object tmp = GetCar(mycar2,2).value;
if ((tmp as int?) != null && (int)tmp == 1)
            GetCar(mycar2,2).worked = false;
```

Now you do the cast only if your items is effectively an Integer.

If you like do it in a single line of code:

```
int? temp2 = 0;
if ((temp2 = (GetCar(mycar2,2).value as int?)).HasValue && temp2 == 1)
    GetCar(mycar2,2).worked = false;
```

L-

Comment: thats too much code for me I only want to use `GetCar(mycar, c).value == (string) or (int) or (bool)`

Answer (score 0):

For example you can create two value if, you want to use string and int in the same time.

```
public class Cars
{
    public int intValue { get; set; }
    public string stringValue { get; set; }
    public bool worked { get; set; }
}
public Cars GetCar(int value, Cars c)
{
    c.intValue = value;
    return c;
}
public Cars GetCar(string value, Cars c)
{
    c.stringValue = value;
    return c;
}

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cars c = new Cars();
    string mycar = "ABC-12";
    int mycar2 = 123;

    if (GetCar(mycar, c).stringValue == "ABC")
        GetCar(mycar, c).worked = false;

    if (GetCar(mycar2, c).intValue == 1)
        GetCar(mycar2, c).worked = false;
}
```

This will work, but it's not a nice solution. I need more info about the project to be able to create a good design.

Answer (score 0):

- **Working** because Class Cars is reference type i.e. object and **String** also **reference type** i.e. object
- **Not Working** because Class Cars is reference type i.e. object and **Int** is **value type** i.e. object

That's why

```
    string mycar = "ABC-12";
    int mycar2 = 123;

    if (GetCar(mycar).value == "ABC") // working because reference type==reference type
        GetCar(mycar).worked = false;

    if (GetCar(mycar).value == 1) // error because reference type=value type
        GetCar(mycar).worked = false;
```

I think second if condition should be like

```
    if (GetCar(mycar2).value == 1) 
     GetCar(mycar2).worked = false;
```